# Why is AJAX response returning undefined?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

This is returning `undefined`, even though `var roommate` contains the correct value:

JS

```
roommate = $("#roommate").val();

$.post('roommateSearch.php', 'val=' + $(roommate).val(), function (response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

roommateSearch.php

```
<?php
$roommate = $_POST['val'];
echo "I got your value!".$roommate;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var roommate = $("#roommate").val(); 

$.post('roommateSearch.php', 'val=' + roommate, function (response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

roommates is holding a value so you can use it like this `'val=' + roommate`

No fancy jquery around it.

Comment: Ah!  Of course.  I feel like an idiot.  This worked.  I'll mark the answer as correct in 5 mins (reputation limits).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe clean up the code some. Semicolons are important:

```
var roommate = $("#roommate").val(); //semicolon here

$.post('roommateSearch.php', 'val=' + roommate, function (response) {
    alert(response);
}); //proper function closing here
```

And, `roommate` is already a value so just use its name

Comment: Thanks for the missing semi colon, that is now fixed.  The closings I had, I just copied and pasted wrong.  It is still returning $roommate as "undefined".